# One Keycloak istance configured with multiple domains to avoid Third party cookie block

Tags: java, keycloak, openid

I've a keycloak 16.1.1 instance deployed via bitnami helm on kubernetes and is exposed on domain `auth.mycompany.com`.

Many applications use keycloak as SSO and their domain are for example: `app1.mycompany.com`, `app2.mycompany2.com` and `app3.mycompany3.com`.

This setup generates Third party cookie block errors when apps are opened from Chrome incognito mode or in a iframe in certain browsers (ex: Iphone IOS Chrome).

To solve this error, I could set extraHosts in helm configuration as `auth.mycompany2.com` and `auth.mycompany3.com` but I will lose SSO feature between these different domains.

Is there way to avoid Third party cookie block without losing SSO feature?

Can a custom authenticator (or something else) generate keycloak cookies for all these domains all in once?